# Unable to fetch maps with dismo gmap()

Tags: r, dismo

I am trying to follow a tutorial found here:
https://data.cdrc.ac.uk/tutorial/aa5491c9-cbac-4026-97c9-f9168462f4ac/4b026153-2953-4173-ab44-b24b2fb559fd

Note: the tutorial requires a free login to access

The step I am stuck at in the tutorial is this code:

```
library(raster)
library(dismo)

google.map <- gmap("Camden, London", type = "satellite")
```

I am having trouble getting dismo::gmap() to work. Every time I run it, I get

```
REQUEST_DENIED:Camden,London
Error in dismo::gmap("Camden, London", type = "satellite") : location not found
```

The same error pops up when I point it at any other location. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try reviewing the following:

Google now requires an API key.
       See ?register_google for details.

> ?register_google

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)